# How can I configure a web-based proxy?

Tags: proxy, webserver

I already know how to create some proxies to bypass firewalls with ssh, such as a [SOCKS](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/use-ssh-create-http-proxy) or [PuTTY](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/93106-escaping-the-firewall-with-an-ssh-tunnel-socks-proxy-and-putty) proxy. I also know about [httptunnel](http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html).

But I want/need is something like surfola.com: I'd like to configure a server of mine (Windows or Linux, doesn't matter), access some web server on it, and inside that page I say to which page I want to connect. Them my server will access it and serve it inside another page.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you looked at Squid ?  (and possibly also googled transparent proxying)? - See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy.  Also google "squid url_rewrite_program"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing [PHProxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poxy/) on a simple LAMP stack?

If you need instructions, [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/288158-easy-lamp-server-installation) is a good tutorial on setting up the LAMP stack. From there, you generally just have to drop the PHProxy files into `/var/www` and you should be set. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Glype](http://www.glype.com/) looks like it might be what you want. It's a self hosted online proxy server.

One thing to note is that it doesn't seem like it's very easy to run an access whitelist though it does support blacklisting.